# Hazelcast vs Ehcache + Hazelcast annotations for caching at service/dao layer with Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring, ehcache, distributed-caching, hazelcast

I want to evaluate Hazecast vs Ehcache distributed caches.

First how to use them with Spring + Hibernate project which have standard dao/service layers.
Ehcache has very elegant and easy to use annotations like :

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "test", keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator (
            name = "SpELCacheKeyGenerator", properties = @Property(value = "#key.string(#args[0])", name = "expression")))
```

Is there anything like the above for Hazelcast? I didn't find any information how to use Hazelcast in that fashion for entities/dtos.

Comment: Please limit your questions to single questions. If multiple questions exist open a new question for each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazelcast 2.1 is available and it has implementations for Spring Cache. Spring Cacheable annotation can be easily used with Hazelcast now.

http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.1/manual/multi_html/ch14s03.html

Answer (score 3):

Spring's Cache abstraction is introduced by Spring 3.1 and designed to cache results of methods, reducing thus the number of executions based on the information available in the cache. 
If you want to use EhCache or Hazelcast as Hibernate 2nd level cache then you should use Hibernate's configuration (either with Spring xml or Hibernate annotations). There is no relation between Hibernate L2 cache and Spring's cache.

Spring has two out-of-the-box implementations of cache providers. From official documentation: [Spring Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

> There are two integrations available out of the box, for JDK java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap and Ehcache.

At the moment Hazelcast does not have built-in Spring Cache Provider. But there is a simple implementation post on Hazelcast public group. See the link below;

[Integrating Spring 3.1 Cacheable Annotation with Hazelcast](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hazelcast/EvSJt12mGHI/discussion)